# .htaccess направление на index.html

Tags: .htaccess

Есть настройка `DirectoryIndex index.html`.

Но дело в том что если ввести в строку к примеру `site.ru/query` - появляется `404 not found` и по понятной причине.

Так вот, я хотел бы сделать чтобы любой запрос направлялся на корневой `index.html`  и всё что у меня получилось сделать это только прямой редирект, а это не совсем мне нужно так как при вводе `site.ru/query` идёт переадресация на файл, а мне нужно чтобы запрос (в нашем случае `query`) остался, и я мог прочитать его при помощи `js` но открывался по прежнему `index.html`.

Не подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна единая точка для входа:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

И не забудьте разрешить доступ к динамичным файлам:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/resources/styles/(.*).css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/resources/images/(.*).png
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/resources/images/(.*).jpg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/resources/lib/jquery/(.*).js
```